# why in treeView1 when i make CollapseAll and Expand it's not really doing it ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When i'm running the program i see the root node

Countries

Then when i click on it i see all the countries nodes under Countries
But i want when running the program that it already will show all the countries nodes without clicking on Countries.

I tried in the constructor:

```
PopulateTree(mainPath, treeView1.Nodes.Add("Countries"));
treeView1.CollapseAll();
treeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();
```

The populatetree

```
public void PopulateTree(string dir, TreeNode node)
        {
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.GetDirectories())
            {
                TreeNode t = new TreeNode(d.Name);
                PopulateTree(d.FullName, t);
                node.Nodes.Add(t);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
            {
                TreeNode t = new TreeNode(f.Name);
                node.Nodes.Add(t);
            }
        }
```

But it's not doing it i still see Countries when running the program and to see all the childs nodes i need to click on Countries.

This lines not effect

```
treeView1.CollapseAll();
treeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TreeNode.Expand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.expand(v=vs.110).aspx) expands only `Nodes[0]` down to the next level of nodes. You should use [TreeNode.ExpandAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.expandall(v=vs.110).aspx) to expand all child nodes of Countries node:

```
treeView1.Nodes[0].ExpandAll()
```

NOTE: There is one thing you should keep in mind. If handle is not created for TreeView control, then something like lazy collapsing-expanding is working here. I.e. each node has `expandOnRealization` and `collapseOnRealization` fields. When you are trying to expand node before tree handle is created, then just `expandOnRealization` flag is set to true. No `TVM_EXPAND` windows messages are sent to actually expand that node. Same for collapsing. When tree node is realized, then there is [following code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNode.cs,6c271c08f6e4c23b,references) executed:

```
// If node expansion was requested before the handle was created,
// we can expand it now.
if (expandOnRealization) {
    Expand();
}

// If node collapse was requested before the handle was created,
// we can expand it now.
if (collapseOnRealization) {
    Collapse();
}
```

So, if node was marked both for collapsing and expanding, then ***it would be expanded first and then collapsed***. I believe it's your case.